# displayMessage de trayIcon no sale en la barra de tareas java

Tags: java, jframe

Mi problema es que no me sale el mensaje en mi barra de tareas utilizando un **displayMessage**

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
private JFrame parent;
    private PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    private final Image image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Notificacion.png")).getImage();
    private final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Notificacion.png", popup);
    //para el Timer
    private Timer timer;
    ///////////////////////////
    SystemTray systemTray;
```

Constructor de la clase

```
public Notificacion(JFrame frame) {
        this.parent = frame;
        instanciarTray();
        segundoPlano();
    }
```

Los metodos  **instanciarTray()** y **segundoPlano()**

```
private void instanciarTray() {
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    }

    private void segundoPlano() {
        try {
            if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                systemTray.add(trayIcon);
                parent.setVisible(false);

                //Se inicia una tarea cuando se minimiza           
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new miTimerTask(), 2000, 5000);//Se ejecuta cada 5 segundos
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Tengo un método llamado **MensajeTrayIcon** el cual utilizo para llamarlo desde mi clase **miTimerTask** la cual se ejecuta cada X segundos pero no me funciona, no me sale el mensaje de notificación.

```
public void MensajeTrayIcon(String texto, MessageType tipo) {
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Advertencia.", texto, tipo);
    }
```

Clase **miTimerTask**

```
public class miTimerTask extends TimerTask{

    Controlador controlador = new Controlador();
    Notificacion notificacion = new Notificacion();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        buscarAchivosExtenciones();
    }

    public void buscarAchivosExtenciones(){
        controlador.buscarArchivosPndUnicos(new File("D:\\Gerardo\\Sustemas\\Java\\Netbans\\Alerta\\Alerta\\src\\CarpetaDirectorio\\Nueva carpeta"));
        notificacion.MensajeTrayIcon("Haciendo algo: ", MessageType.INFO);
    }
}
```

Si yo llamo mi método de mensaje dentro de **segundoPlano** me sale el mensaje en la barra de notificaciones pero solo una sola vez, yo necesito que salga cada vez que el sistema realice una acción, por eso lo llamo dentro de mi clase **miTimerTask** pero no me funciona la llamada, nose que estoy haciendo mal. Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E podido solucionar mi problema se la siguiente manera. La base de mi problema es que estaba haciendo una clase a parte de mi clase **Notificacion**, el mensaje no salia porque la clase **miTimerTask** no estaba incluida dentro de la clase **Notificacion** lo cual debia meter **miTimerTask** dentro como una clase interna, así de este modo el mensaje logre que salga, quedando de la siguiente manera mi clase **Notificacion**

```
public class Notificacion {

    ArrayList<String> keyArray = new ArrayList<>();
//    LeerArchivos leer = new LeerArchivos();
    private JFrame parent;
    private PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    private final Image image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("notificaciones.png")).getImage();
    private final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Notificacion.png", popup);
    //para el Timer
    private Timer timer;
    ///////////////////////////
    SystemTray systemTray;

    public Notificacion() {
    }

    public void instanciarTray() {
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    }

    public void segundoPlano() {
        try {
            if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                systemTray.add(trayIcon);

                //Se inicia una tarea cuando se minimiza           
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new miTimerTask(), 1000, segundos());//Se ejecuta cada 5 segundos
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sistema no soporta systemTray", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR);
        }
    }


//    Muestra una burbuja con la accion que se realiza
    public void MensajeTrayIcon(String texto, MessageType tipo) {
//        System.out.println("pasa por aqui");
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Advertencia.", texto, tipo);
//        System.out.println("texto: " + texto + " tipo " + tipo);
    }
//  Clase interna.
    class miTimerTask extends TimerTask {  

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //logica de la clase + llamada del metodo MensajeTrayIcon().
        }
    }
}
```

De esta forma logre mostrar el msnsaje de mi trayicon con determinadas acciones en segundo plano. Espero que les sirva, gracias.